# Checkbox without text does not align horizontally

Tags: android

It appears that a checkbox without text behaves like it does have a small space text. Centering it horizontally moves it a bit to the left.

Any ideas on how to work around this inconvenience?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"` removes the small space text. Then just let the constraint layout center the view.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that (probably) the `CheckBox` element is an extension of a `TextView` with a `DrawableLeft` set.

If you want only the box without Text, would be probably better to use a [ToggleButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) with the custom image as [state selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Another possible solution is to create your own `CheckBox` extension and override `getSuggestedMinimumWidth()`
 [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20374661/4700782)

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: The same problem occurs with `ToggleButton` after setting the `textOn` and `textOff` to `@null`. I wanted to have padding on the checkbox without text but I haven't been able to find a straight forward solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Material checkbox with no text. It will align in center.

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:buttonTint="@color/on_primary_app"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```